# how to serve all static images on my asp.net website separately

Tags: asp.net, image, iis

My website (developed in ASP.NET) and has 75 GB of images and those are served along with web application. Meaning there are on the same server.

Now I want to move all the images to an external server and using another domain. This new domain is specifically just to server images.

If I move all my images to another domain, I will lose SEO (Google indexed) results.

Considering this situation, please help me out with the following.

1. Which web server is better to serve images very fast? Which Operating system and web server combination is better to serve this purpose?
2. If images are moved to another domain, what is the alternative way that I can still have the same URLs for the existing images? Is there any facility to give alias name that will point out to the new domain?

Answer (score 0):

Since the advent of ASP net MVC MS have Routes helpers
Since MVC it's build on top of ASP.net you can use id to redirect to the url of the images to the another domain
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx

[Using ASP.NET routing to serve static files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149750/using-asp-net-routing-to-serve-static-files)

Comment: We can do this way but there is some performance issue. As these are static images, I don't want worker process to process the static file requests.