# How to get a default html page on MVC3 site

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have added an MVC3 web application to an existing website that consists of plain old html files. This works great when you request a specific file but what didn't occur to me was that by changing the site to use .Net 4 it no longer took any notice of the default documents setting in IIS (IIS 6 in this case). So for example I can request www.something.com/index.html but if I request www.something.com I get a resource not found error page. Is there a MapRoute in Global.asax I can specify to map the site route url to index.html?

Comment: Did you read the Phil Haack [blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx) I have linked to in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7460870/how-to-get-a-default-html-page-on-mvc3-site/7460903#7460903) about configuring your IIS 6.0 in order to support extensionless urls which by default IIS 6.0 doesn't support?

Comment: Yes I did but I'm not sure it was entirely relevant to my problem. I just want to redirect requests to the site root to index.html. Phil's post was more about mapping to controllers. I'll go back and take another look tonight.

Comment: if you want to execute some controller action when the user requests `http://www.something.com/` you definitely need a wildcard mapping as explained by Phil Haack. If you want to serve a static HTML page then simply add this html page as default document in the properties of the virtual directory in the IIS console.

Comment: That's the problem I'm trying to fix. The default document is defined correctly for the site. When I set .Net Framework to version 2 it works correctly but when I set it to version 4 it doesn't redirect to index.html. That's why I'm thinking the IgnoreRoute option may be worth trying. Unfortunately I won't be in a position to check until this evening (UTC+12:00)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("");
```

Allows the request to fall through to the default documents defined in the site configuration. I only have a single controller and route in this project that I use for ajax requests from the client. I want the rest of the site to continue to behave as it did when it was just plain html. With *routes.IgnoreRoute("")* the MVC3 app ignores the request which allows IIS to return the default document. Thanks all for your suggestions.

Comment: This just throws an error in MVC3: "The route URL cannot start with a '/' or '~' character and it cannot contain a '?' character.
Parameter name: routeUrl"

Comment: Same issue here cannot contain a '~' or '?'

Comment: It should be `routes.IgnoreRoute("");`

Comment: Apologies, this was a solution I used at the time but clearly this has been changed in an update. Have updated the answer to reflect.

Answer (score 6):

Looks like something has changed, I had to do

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("");
```

ASP.NET complained about the route starting with "/"

Comment: Confirmed: `routes.IgnoreRoute("/")` gives an error - this answer works as intended.

Answer (score 2):

in global.asax you can try to define a rules like this one

```
 routes.MapRoute("", "index.html", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
```

But I'm afraid that with IIS 6 you have to handle the `Wild card mapping`.

Comment: I'm not sure if I expressed my question clearly. I don't want to map a request for index.html to a controller. I want to redirect a request to the site root to index.html.

Comment: After the comments in your answer I understand your problem. Try looking at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149750/using-asp-net-routing-to-serve-static-files/3112192#3112192

Answer (score 1):

That's normal. IIS 6.0 does not support extensionless urls. You will need a [wildcard mapping](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx) as explained by Phil Haack.