# Asp.Net MVC navigating to shared folder view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, shared

I have a view in Asp.Net MVC project shared folder which is not tied to any controller or its action. Assuming it has all static html content, how can I see that view with url in a browser?

Comment: good question, if we could do it!!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149750/using-asp-net-routing-to-serve-static-files.  Failing that, the same way you serve up any other view, by writing a controller method to service the URL.

Answer (score 0):

I installed notfoundmvc nuget package and I am able to navigate to share folder views now.