# Routing path and keep content referenced

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, path, routes

On my project I have a folder where I have to place different sites, each site is developed with angular and contains .html files.

That's the path of one site, and that it Works:

- ~/Sites/One/Index.Html
- www.Mystye.com/Sites/One/Index.Html

But I want this other Path:

- www.Mystye.com/SiteOne/ and return the content from :> ~/Sites/One/Index.Html

I don't know how to do that because I need too keep referenced all content inside the folder "~/Sites/One" of the project.

Creating a MapPageRoute, will allow me to do that, but the problem is that the web content will try to load files from "/SiteOne/js/xxxx.js" and not from "/Sites/One/js/xxxx.js". Maybe ther's a way to redirect all requests that start with "/SiteOne/" ...

Comment: Just a thought, but wouldn't it be simpler just to copy the content of the HTML files into views, which would allow you to configure your routes any way you want (including with .html extension).

Comment: Yeah, you are right that's what I thought... but the problem is that every time that the company that develops the front-end have a new version... makes me crazy raplacing/updating files...

Comment: I have founded this solution and it works for me

http://stackoverflow.com/a/3952250/1520494