# Angular2 and ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, angular

I'm teaching myself Angular2 (the wave of the future, apparently) and I'm getting experimental. I followed Ibrahim Uludag's tutorial here:

http://www.ibrahimuludag.com/2016/01/angular2-and-visual-studio.html

and that works just fine. But I want to go one step further and use an MVC project instead of a TypeScript project as Ibrahim suggests. I'm using a simple structure (one controller, one view) and I've added the Angular2 JavaScript references to my view (along with header, body etc.). I had to prefix the filenames with a slash, otherwise the server interprets them as as controller / view references. That part works fine.

The problem I have is with this command:

```
System.config ({
    packages: {
        app: {
            format: 'register',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        }
    }
});
System.import ('app/boot')
    .then (null, console.error.bind(console));
```

I can see from the debugger that it's trying to find http://localhost/Default/app/boot - the "Default" part being the name of my controller (the same problem that arose when I didn't include a slash in the direct JavaScript references). I've tried prefixing the "app/boot" with a slash ("/app/boot") and this sort of works: it will find boot.ts but not any of the dependencies, again, adding the controller name to the URL.

Does anyone have any suggestions or, at the very least, a reference of where I can find information about the System.import directive?

Thank.

Comment: The `System.import` call tells SystemJS to import the main file, in your case it is `boot.js`?

Answer (score 1):

First, I commend you for diving into the world of angular2.

System.import is part of SystemJS. SystemJS is a module loader that angular 2 uses while the new fancy javascript specs are finalized and implemented by browsers.

For more information on System.import see:
https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs

I believe your issue is with the way MVC is serving static files, not with the way SystemJs is attempting to load modules.

See this article:
[Using ASP.NET routing to serve static files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149750/using-asp-net-routing-to-serve-static-files)

In your RouteConfig.cs file:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("app/{file}.js");
```

This should tell MVC to ignore js files located in the app folder at the root of your project.  SystemJS should then be able to load your modules properly.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'll give it a shot and will let you know.

Comment: Oh, and thank you for the references. I'll check those out, too.

Comment: Nope. That didn't seem to do it. The files are on GitHub at: https://github.com/widgetinc/Angular-2-MVC if anyone is interested in having a crack at it.