# How to route Static Files Dynamically in Asp.Net & Asp.Net Core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

How to route Static Files Dynamically in Asp.Net & Asp.Net Core

Hi All, i have to build an application , which will have both static files & dynamic content to be displayed, how can i do this with Asp.Net Core & Asp.Net MVC

Example

```
       I have site 

            http://dummy.com/
```

now there are some routes where i need to server its default content but depending on wether the request is from mobile or Desktop i need to change the files

```
          Ex : http://dummy.com/category1
               index.html
               index-m.html

               in this category1 has a folder & in the site and it has two static files like above
               now when there is a request for "http://dummy.com/category1" i have to check wether its from mobile or desktop
               if its mobile "index-m.html" should be server else "index.html" should be served

         Ex : http://dummy.com/category/getcategories

              this is a dynamic route , when this is requested it should go to its default Action method and get the result
```

Can any one help me, what do i have to do here to get this

Comment: Serving a different html based on the type of a device is... outdated. A better idea is to have a single html file that has responsive design.

Comment: @TeodorKurtev the reason for doing this is , our sites SEO focused, we want the mobile version to be light & fast

Answer (score 1):

To serve static files, in RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes), add the following ignore rules:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{file}.html");
```

Please see the following answer for additional information:
[Using ASP.NET routing to serve static files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149750/using-asp-net-routing-to-serve-static-files)

Answer (score -3):

Use javascript to detect screen resolution.

If screen resolution width is less than 800 pixels, redirect you page to mobile version.

Please let me know if I can help further.