# Asp.net website loads error page in place of wanted ng-view

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs

I have an Asp.net (c#, **not Asp.net MVC**) web site.

Recently I added webform using angular.
Angular Routing script:

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
    .when("/Obligations", {
        templateUrl: "views/Obligation.html"
    })
    .when("/:Id", {
        templateUrl: "views/clients.html"
    })
    .when("/Edit/:Id/:Type", {
        templateUrl: "views/EditClient.html"
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    })
});
```

Web Form content:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="..." />
  <script src="..."></script>
  <!--Relevante css and js links-->
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ClientIDMode="Static" ID="content2" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1">
  <div ng-app="ClientsApp">
      <ng-view></ng-view>
  </div>
</asp:Content>
```

In root folder I have "views" folder contains the html view files.
In development enviroment everything works fine.
But when I uploaded the version to server, I get something strange: in place of getting wanted view, I get default error page.
both development and production enviroment work on iis 8.5.

I googled my problem by found nothing, most of similar issues are in Asp.net MVC, and answers seem unrelated.

What can be the problem?

Comment: Any error details? Logs?

Comment: What log can I search? in my log table there is no error. in eventviewer There is also nothing.

Comment: you see default error page for asp/net or default error page for iis?

Comment: @tym32167 for this specific site.

Comment: so, if you can see error for this specific site, it means that you have error in your app. If you cannot see it in logs, it means that you not handle all errors. You can try to catch Application_Error event in global asax and log them and see details. More info here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/24395wz3.aspx

Comment: @tym32167 ok it seems 404 error.

Comment: so, you can check you requested paths and existed files

Comment: @tym32167 folder structure is the same in developement and production.

Comment: so, either you have not files requested, neither your IIS/app is not serving static files. Im not web dev, but I believe you can google it in 5 secs ( i.e. https://stackoverflow.com/a/1185171/312041 )