# Allow all extensions in ASP.NET MVC URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, url-routing

I am working on ASP.NET MVC web application and I want to allow all file extensions in URL of my application. I have tried adding

```
<add name="ChatFileHandler" 
     path="*.docx" 
     verb="GET"
     type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" 
     preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
```

inside `/<system.webServer>/<handlers>` in Web.config but it will only allow .docx file extensions in url. I want my url to be `/Download/{FileName}.extension`.

How can I achieve my desired functionality with less workaround.

Regards.

**Edit:**
I have also tried adding below route setting in AreaRegistration.

`context.MapRoute(
                "FileDownload",
                "Download/{fileName}.{datatype}",
                new { controller = "Download", action = "Download", fileId = UrlParameter.Optional, fileName = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );`

Controller:

`public ActionResult Download(string fileId, string fileName, string datatype)
{ }`

Alongwith `<add ChatFileHandler ... />` with path="*.docx" in Web.config. Adding these i am able to get fileName and datatype in controller's action method. But I don't want to add handler for every file extension as they will be in hundreds.

Comment: Do you not understand what this , path="*.docx", means?

Comment: This means any file with extension ".docx" is allowed in url. I want to allow all file extensions in url.

Comment: So, try path=".*"

Comment: Possible [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149750/using-asp-net-routing-to-serve-static-files)

Comment: @RyanWilson path=".*" didn't work. @Lennart not a duplicate. Because the answer of question means i have to ignore all file extensions like `routes.IgnoreRoute("{file}.js");`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could disable static files handler for specific path (and HTTP verbs) by adding following handler in `web.config`:

```
<system.webServer>
<!-- -->
    <handlers>
        <add name="Download" path="/Download/*" verb="GET" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```